# gulp watch is not watching after first call

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have a problem with **gulp watch**.
After I call it for the first time, and after I make changes to the sass files, there are no changes in the terminal. Only if I re-invoke the gulp-watch I see the change of styles. 
My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
'use strict'

var gulp = require('gulp');

var sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/css/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
         }))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public/css"));
})

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/javascript/*.js')
      .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascript'));
})

gulp.task('imgs', function() {
    return gulp.src("assets/images/*.+(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)")
      .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
            interlaced: true
        }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("public/images"))
})

gulp.task("watch", function() {
    watch("assets/*.html", ["html"]);
    watch("assets/css/*.scss", ["sass"]);
    watch("assets/javascript/*.js", ["scripts"]);
    watch("assets/images/*.+(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)", ["imgs"]);
});

gulp.task("default", ["html", "sass", "scripts", "imgs", "watch"]);
```

Question. 
Why gulp watch does not track changes after calling **gulp watch** or **gulp default**?

Comment: Issue solved, was `gulp.watch("assets/css/main.scss", ["scss"]);`

now `gulp.watch("assets/css/**/*.scss", ["scss"]);`